# Win8 bluetooth keyboard issue

Tags: bluetooth, windows-8-preview, wireless-keyboard

I installed the Windows 8 developer preview but somehow it doesnt work with the apple wireless keyboard/ Intel Centrino Bluetooth 3.0 stick.

Windows says it has installed the sticks driver properly but when i try installing the driver from intels homepage manually the installation exits with a compatibility error(comp. mode windows7)...

How can i fix this?

Would it help to install BootCamp?

Comment: Drivers are very specific when it comes to Operating Systems. You wouldn't be able to get it to install on Windows Developer Preview. It isn't meant to be used as your primary OS, as there are several applications that refuse to run on Windows 8.

Comment: What do you think causes the problem? The bt stick or the keyboard? Is there a way to "skip" the error message of the driver?

Comment: It may not be possible to skip the error message as the issue is incompatibility. You should try another bt dongle.